# How to delay onCreate method in activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I have an application where I use `Firebase store` and `datastore` for local file management
In `Application.kt`, I download my user with role admin and set it to datastore in short:

```
    private suspend fun operateUserModel() {
        val uid = firebaseManager.getCurrentUserUid()
        if(uid.isNotEmpty()) {
            val actualUserModel = firebaseManager.getUserModel(uid)
            if (actualUserModel != null) putUserModel(actualUserModel, uid)
        }
    }
```

Everything works, but this param `model.role` has to be checked in `MainActivity`, and MainActivity runs too fast, like 100ms, and I couldn't set the proper first route for this. Of course, I could use workarounds and set up an empty (loading) screen and then navigate through when the data is available, but is it possible to make it I think, more correct using MainActivity?
Here, I use like:

```
    private val userDataStore by inject<UserDataStore>()
    private var userModel: UserModel? = null
```

then `onCreate`

```
[...]
// and here if I use  
val userModel = userDataStore.getModel<UserModel>().firstOrNull()
// userModel is null, after 100ms~ it would be the value from firestore
                      NavigationComponent(
                            navController = navController,
                            firebaseManager = firebaseManager
                        )
```

Comment: You don't.  If you think you need to, you're architecting your application wrong.

Comment: OK, what could be better approach in my case that you could assume as good architecting seeing exactly my case. I have ideas, probably it will work but what is your recommendation